# updating 2d pointer using openmp in c++

Tags: c++

The problem with the code 2 is that delE can not be updated because of the presence parallel region (which is quite obvious). code 1, however, is not up to the mark and showing ambiguous results. I will be obliged if any of you can provide correct solution to run either code 1 or code 2 in parallel.

Here grad_compute is returning a 2d pointer which is needed to be stored or added for each parallel loop. norm_delE and delE are declared as 3d and 2d pointer respectively.

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8) 

for (int k = 0; k < no_of_sources; k++)
{
    double** gnorm = grad_compute(/*parameters*/);

// code 1   
/*  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) 
    {
        norm_delE[i][j][k] = gnorm[i][j]; } }    */     

// code 2    
/*  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) 
    { delE[i][j] += gnorm[i][j]; } }   */
}
```

I'll appreciate if you require further information.

Answer (score 1):

Edit and Update:
for code1 there is no need to use gnorm and result of grad_compute directly assigned to norm_delE but dimension of norm_delE should be changed to become [no_of_sources] * [rows] * [cols].

for code2 because multiple thread ,at the same time, write to the delE array , each thread should be limited to update only some rows
so we create 2 omp for loop one for code1 and the other for code2

Also, the memory that aquired by grad_compute shoule be released by a function such as free_memory, although for memory management, use of std::vector or unique_ptr is recommended.

```
#pragma omp parallel  num_threads(8) 
{
    //code 1
    #pragma omp for 
    for (int k = 0; k < no_of_sources; k++)
    {
        norm_delEk[k] = grad_compute(/*parameters*/);   
    }
    //code 2

    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
     {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) 
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < no_of_sources; k++)
            {
                delE[i][j] += norm_delE[k][i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
//memory that acquired should be released
free_memory(norm_delE);
```

Comment: I tried improving my code as you suggested. However, i am still getting ambiguity in the results. Just a normal for works fine. As soon as i implement it in parallel it shows some weird results. Please visit https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B66p6XimmUkaanZXVHhHdzF3M00/view?usp=sharing   for visual interpretation.

Comment: result still the same

Comment: I do not know what is the problem . I tested it in a simple example that computes sum of numbers from 1 to 16 that gives 136: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c04cdcd5c42d9ebb your problem may be due to memory limits

Comment: your solution seems correct. However,the problem I see is that my threads are overriding on one another somehow. Which i couldn't solve.